# Como fazer uma consulta SQL em Python?

Tags: mysql, python, sql, script

Eu estou querendo montar um script em python para rodar com o mysql. Não tenho praticamente nada de experiência em python e queria alguma ajudinha. No meu script em SQL tenho alguns parâmetros que recebem o resultado de um SELECT:

```
SET @fiscal_year_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM fiscal_years);
SET @elite_since = (SELECT CAST(start_period AS DATE) FROM fiscal_years WHERE id = @fiscal_year_id);
SET @fiscal_year = (SELECT MAX(fiscal_year) FROM fiscal_years);
```

Porém gostaria de transformar esses parâmetros acima em python. Lembrando que o segundo "SET" pega do parâmetro acima. Como eu poderia colocar em python e depois usar estes parâmetros em outras partes do script?

Comment: Modifiquei o título pois julguei que assim seria mais fácil de encontrar sua pergunta nas engines de busca e assim o conjunto pergunta e respostas ajudarão mais pessoas. Caso discorde e queira restaurar o título antigo você pode fazer em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/564071/revisions restaurando a versão anterior.

Answer (score 2):

Para usar MySQL em Python é preciso instalar o pacote MySQL `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

Faz-se a ligação à base de dados e depois executa-se as queries.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM fiscal_years")

fiscal_year_id = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

mycursor.execute("SELECT CAST(start_period AS DATE) FROM fiscal_years WHERE id = %s", (fiscal_year_id,))

elite_since = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

mycursor.execute("SELECT MAX(fiscal_year) FROM fiscal_years")

fiscal_year = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

print(fiscal_year_id)
print(elite_since)
print(fiscal_year)
```

Comment: esse script funcionou mais ou menos, porque nessa parte: "mycursor.execute("SELECT CAST(start_period AS DATE) FROM fiscal_years WHERE id = %s", (fiscal_year_id))'' dá este erro: "...prepare_for_mysql raise ProgrammingError(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: int(11), it must be of type list, tuple or dict"

Comment: Desculpe, tinha um erro. Faltava uma vírgula.

Comment: Eu tinha colocado essa virgula porém ainda da erro. Poderia ser  porque o resultado é data? O erro que ocorre é: "TypeError: CMySQLCursor.execute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'operation'"

Comment: "operation" refere-se ao statement de SQL